# Django - Using TimeField() as a foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a `Meeting` model which has `meeting_hour` getting its value from `MeetingHour` model. But I'm getting an error as follows after submitting form:

`Cannot assign "datetime.time(14, 0)": "Meeting.meeting_hour" must be a "MeetingHour" instance.`

I know its because of I'm not using `MeetingHour` as a foreign key correctly, but don't know how can I fix it. Here are my codes:

`models.py`

```
class MeetingHour(models.Model):
    hour = models.TimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.hour

class Meeting(models.Model):
    participant_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    participant_email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    meeting_date = models.DateField()
    meeting_hour = models.ForeignKey(MeetingHour, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    is_scheduled = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.participant_name
```

`views.py`

```
def index(request):
    context = {
        'schedules': Meeting.objects.all()
    }
    if request.method == "POST":
        participant_name = request.POST.get('name')
        participant_email = request.POST.get('email')
        meeting_date = str(request.POST.get('date'))
        meeting_hour = str(request.POST.get('hour'))
        converted_meeting_date = datetime.strptime(request.POST.get('date'), "%Y-%m-%d").date() if meeting_date else None
        converted_meeting_hour = datetime.strptime(request.POST.get('hour'), "%H:%M").time() if meeting_hour else None
        subject = 'Meeting'
        message = f'Hi, {participant_name} ! \nYour meeting date: {meeting_date}, hour: {meeting_hour}'
        from_email = settings.SERVER_EMAIL
        recipient_list = [participant_email]
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list)
        if request.POST.get('email'):
            Meeting.objects.create(
                participant_name = request.POST.get('name'),
                participant_email = request.POST.get('email'),
                meeting_date = converted_meeting_date,
                meeting_hour = converted_meeting_hour,
                is_scheduled = True
            )
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Comment: You have to create an instance of `MeetingHour` first and then assign it to `Meeting.meeting_hour`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `MeetingHour` instance for foriegnkey. Also you must check `email` before calling `send_email`:

```
def index(request):
    context = {
        'schedules': Meeting.objects.all()
    }
    if request.method == "POST" and request.POST.get('email'):
        participant_name = request.POST.get('name')
        participant_email = request.POST.get('email')
        meeting_date = str(request.POST.get('date'))
        meeting_hour = str(request.POST.get('hour'))
        converted_meeting_date = datetime.strptime(request.POST.get('date'), "%Y-%m-%d").date() if meeting_date else None
        converted_meeting_hour = datetime.strptime(request.POST.get('hour'), "%H:%M").time() if meeting_hour else None
        subject = 'Meeting'
        message = f'Hi, {participant_name} ! \nYour meeting date: {meeting_date}, hour: {meeting_hour}'
        from_email = settings.SERVER_EMAIL
        recipient_list = [participant_email]
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list)
        hour, _ = MeetingHour.objects.get_or_create(hour = converted_meeting_hour)
        Meeting.objects.create(
            participant_name = request.POST.get('name'),
            participant_email = request.POST.get('email'),
            meeting_date = converted_meeting_date,
            meeting_hour = hour,
            is_scheduled = True
        )
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Comment: Man, but is it possible to do this without creating instance of ```MeetinHour``` ? Because I have fixed meeting hours, for example, only 14:00 and 15:00 for each day

Comment: Yes, remove the `MeetingHour` model and make the field a `ChoiceField` with your available times as choices.

Comment: @suhailvs, man, hello, have a good day. Can you check please my this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61156491/django-form-save-is-not-creating-modelform ? Last days my question reach very few people, and can't tag someone. Please, help me.

Answer (score 1):

Since `meeting_hour` is a `ForeignKey` to your `MeetingHour` model, you must get an object from the `MeetingHour` table and save it to the `meeting_hour` field in your `Meeting` model.

For example:

`meeting_hour = MeetingHour.objects.get(hour=converted_meeting_hour)`

`Meeting.objects.create(..., .., .., meeting_hour=meeting_hour)`

If you think of it from a database perspective, the `meeting_hour` field from the `Meeting` model is just the `id` of the `MeetingHour` field. This means Django needs an actual reference to that field either via an instance of the object or an `id` to store the correct value in the database.

Comment: Man, hello, have a good day. Can you check please my this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61156491/django-form-save-is-not-creating-modelform ? Last days my question reach very few people, and can't tag someone. Please, help me.